# HTC Desire HD Android 2.2 disable screen shut off when timer is running

Tags: htc-desire, stock-android, screen-timeout

I tried to use the timer for a countdown of 3 minutes. 1 minute in, the screen shut off and the phone locked, disabling the countdown.

After 4 minutes, I realised what had happened. Is there a way to disable the screen shut off just when the timer is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to install KeepScreen application from Android market and configure it to disable screen timeout when your timer application is running.

Answer (score 1):

The **Tasker** app should be able to do this as well.